# scrollIntoView is not scrolling into view

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, js-scrollintoview

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('tabAnchor').scrollIntoView(true); return false;">
    TEXT TO GO TO WARRANTY
</a>
...
<!-- A LOT OF HTML -->
...
<a id="tr_tab_2";">Warranty</a>
```

The issue is that it changes tabs and scrolls a bit, but it doesn't actually scroll to a point where I can see the selected tab. It just goes down to the title of the tab.

Is there a way to scroll it under the tab title instead of just to the title?

**SOLUTION**

In case anyone stumbles upon it, this fixes it:

```
<a href="#" onclick="scrollIntoWarranty(); return false;">

function scrollIntoWarranty() {
    var offset = 50;
    var el = document.querySelector("#tr_tab_2");
    window.scroll({ top: (el.offsetTop - offset), left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

Comment: maybe you should share the html markup to clarify the issue

Comment: I actually came across something that fixes it. Updated the question. Thanks for reply!